# How to parse "91212" as "Hmmss" in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

The code:

```
var str = "91212";
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "Hmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The error:

```
"91212" is not a valid DateTime
```

It seems c# try to use `H` to match `91`, which is incorrect hour.

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you not add a leading zero on the string in case its `length` equals 5? I think `HHmmss` may be better interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`H`, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), is interpreted as:

> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.

so the behaviour you are seeing is as-designed and as documented.

Could you prepend `91212` with a zero?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to force it to 6 characters and define the format string accordingly. The following code:

```
        var str = "91212";
        if (str.Length == 5)
        {
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        var dtDate = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dtDate.ToShortTimeString());
```

Results in:

```
9:12 AM
```